# Access properties of referenced object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

User schema:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
        },
        following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Me:

```
"following": [
        "5f0fd1874f2f4556f00c1f14", //in MongoDB it's ObjectId("5f0fd1874f2f4556f00c1f14")
        "5f0fe1e182878023cc54eb0a"  //in MongoDB it's ObjectId("5f0fe1e182878023cc54eb0a")
],
"_id": "5f0fd1470c39e43cf8a843ad",
"username": "David",
```

And there are other users with `username` property (e.g. `"username": "Jeff"`).

In React I can access **my** `username` like this:

```
<p> {user.user.username} </p>
```

However when I want to access the `following` users then I just get their `id` in string.

```
<p> {user.user.following} </p>
```

If I want to access **their** `username` then I get undefined error.

```
<p> {user.user.following.username} </p>
```

Is it because `following` array contains strings? I specifically did this in the `User` schema:

```
following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
```

I thought I will get back the users with properties and all.

How do I access the properties of these users in the `following` array? I would like to map through them and output their `username` in my React app.

Comment: You need to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the references, which replaces the id in `following` with the actual DB object.

Comment: amazing! thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) helped.

Need to populate the references.

On the backend:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).populate("following");
```

And then map through it on the client side:

```
{user.user.following.map((a) => {
  return <p>{a.username}</p>;
})}
```